# Unable to upload media files to S3 using Django

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I have been trying to upload my media files to my Amazon S3 bucket for my Django project, but I am unable to do so, only the static files get uploaded on the S3 bucket. Not sure what I am doing wrong here, my settings file is as below settings.py

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, it's hard to read, and for those of us using dark mode, also dazzling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to resolve the issue, I just needed to add an image on my website and it created a media folder on the S3 bucket

Comment: Thanks for this! So obvious yet so hard to think about.

Answer (score 2):

***What you can try..***

***1. Make sure you have the right S3 Permissions and Policy in place. Access 'Policy' via permissions tab in AWS S3 console for your specific bucket.***

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<your_bucket_name>/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<your_bucket_name>/images/"
        }
    ]
}
```

***2. Install WhiteNoiseMiddleware & django-storages in your project environment.***

```
pip install whitenoise
pip install django-storages
```

***3. Add the following to `MIDDLEWARE=` in `settings.py`***

```
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
```

***4. Following additions in `settings.py` are required to handle URLs from S3 correctly. The handling is done by django middleware & django-storages automatically***

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % os.environ['BUCKET_NAME']
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_KEY']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_ACC_KEY']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['BUCKET_NAME']
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
```

***5. For aiming uploads into a precise S3 Bucket folder. (Additional)***

In setting.py set media root:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
```

In models.py use `ImageFiled` and add `upload_to=` takes in a folder name and creates it with the first upload!:

```
image_variable = models.ImageField(null=True, default="{default_filename)", upload_to='uploads/')
```

Reference: [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) , [whiteNoiseMiddelware](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/), [S3 Access Troubleshooting](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-file-folder/)

Comment: My issue had to do with s3 missing the second statement in the policy. Thank you for this solution.